How to efficiently sort a large array in Python?
I'm working on a project where I need to sort a very large array of integers in Python. The array size is around 10 million elements, and I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.
I'm currently using the built-in sorted() function, but I'm wondering if there are any more efficient algorithms or techniques that I should consider for such large datasets. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What type of "array"? And what can you tell us about the integers?

What is the range of the integers?

Can you change the datatype to use a collection that keeps the data sorted as you enter it?

A lot of the places where you need algorithms that differ from the usual set is if you need to operate efficiently on datasets larger than memory. If your data fits in memory, then the typical answers generally apply (and if it doesn't, that's often a place where you sort subsets that fit in memory, and then do a merge sort between them). That said, as Barmar references, the best approaches for persistent larger-than-memory collections is just to keep the data sorted at-rest, since it's easy to do an individual insertion cheaply with the obvious (bisection) algorithm.
